# A fair division algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have n bags, each with a random number of balls from 1 to n. I wish to distribute these bags to three people, such that each receives a roughly equal number of balls. More rigorously, I would like to minimize the number of balls that the guy with the maximum number of balls gets.

I have been thinking about this for a while now, but am unable to devise a greedy or dynamic algorithm as the subproblem after one step is different from the original problem. Any help in the direction to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Greedy would be to hand each next bag to the person who has the fewest balls at that point. The result will probably be better if you sort the bags by descending size first, but of course it's not guaranteed to be optimal.

Comment: For example `2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6`: the optimal solution is `{6}, {3, 3}, {2, 2, 2}` but the greedy algorithm will give `{6}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2}`.

Comment: Are you clear on how to solve this brute force?

Comment: This problem is usually referred to as the [3-way partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning).

Comment: Do you prefer to see the psudo code or implementation in Python3?

Comment: @Thomas yeah that would be a good approximate solution, however I needed to get optimal solution.

Comment: DanielHao: I would love to see pseudo code for the problem. user1984: yes, but brute force would take exponential time, which is not useful for me. @Stef The article was helpful, I think the Pseudo-polynomial algorithm would work for my requirements. But I am unable to find proper references on the wiki page. If you have something, I would love if you share it.